# How to dynamically add function with changing parameters to onclick event?

Tags: javascript, events, parameters

I'm adding an onlick event dynamically to a series of anchor elements.  For each anchor element I need to use different parameter values, in the form of variables.  when using the following event listener in a loop:

```
anchor.addEventListener("click", () => { task(title, author) });
```

`title` and `author` for every anchor element's onclick end up the same (they are all the value of `title` and `author` at their last iteration).  I'd like them to represent the values of the variables at the particular iteration in the loop.  Here's a minimal working code example:

```
for (obj of objTasks) {
    title = obj.title;
    author = obj.author;

    var anchor = document.createElement("a");

    anchor.addEventListener("click", () => { task(title, author) });
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use global variables like that, because it won't work as expected ... declare `for(let obj` and `const title =` and `const author =` and you'll find the code works

Comment: What is the issue you're having? It seems like you already solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring your variables globally - use `let` because it's block-scoped (`var` is function scoped):

```
for (let obj of objTasks) {
    let title = obj.title;
    let author = obj.author;
    let anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.addEventListener("click", () => { task(title, author) });
}
```